# Byte[] Key Encryption C# Aes

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am making a program to save my passwords, and I am using the Aes encryption method to encrypt and decrypt my files.
Now here's my problem, I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do it.

Everytime I run the program it generates a new *KEY* and a new *IV*, but for the program to read the files I need to have the same key and iv every time I open the program again.

They key and the IV is stored as a `byte[]` both of which should be "secret"

The bytes they create are sometimes too much for the compiler to read, or it just freaks out.

Is there any way I can set these as Constants? or is it better of saving it to a file?

Comment: I've never seen a compiler "freak out". I've seen programmers freak out though, and slashdotees that have to read these "very informative" error descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They key and the IV is stored as a byte[] both of which should be "secret"

Not quite. The IV is not a secret. The IV should be *different* and random for each thing you encrypt, but it can be stored in plaintext. They should be generated by as CSPRNG. Encrypting the IV doesn't really serve a purpose.

> Everytime I run the program it generates a new KEY and a new IV

Your key should derived from another password. That is, your app should ask for a "master" password, which is run through something like PBKDF2, and the output of that is used as the AES key for what you encrypt and decrypt. With this approach, your application doesn't need to store the key at all.

---

Consider if you need to "encrypt" the passwords at all. If you are using the passwords for validation, such as sign on, then hashing them with something like bcrypt is better.

Also keep in mind this is an *extremely* difficult thing to get right. So far, you haven't mentioned any authentication in your encryption (such as Encrypt-then-Mac), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Still very new at this (infact still in school)
But I'm doing all I can to learn more

Comment: A simple, secure and generally used method is to prefix the encrypted data with the IV.

Comment: @vcsjones Unfortunately CBC is still the mode of choice for most; in that case the IV should be unpredictable (to the attacker), not just different.

Comment: Yes, generated by a CSPRNG. I made that more clear with an edit.